# On a sheet of paper it is drawn a point $A$ and 2 lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ which intersect outside the sheet in a point B.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

On a sheet of paper it is drawn a point $A$ and 2 lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ which intersect outside the sheet in a point B. How one can draw a line $AB$ using only a ruler?

Comment: Pappus’ hexagon theorem might be of use here.

Comment: I know, but how can I use it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341882/find-the-intersection-of-two-lines-entirely-outside-the-given-sheet-of-paper-by is the same question, but with no answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pappus’ hexagon theorem affords a solution.

Draw lines through $A$ intersecting $L_1$ at $C_1$ and $L_2$ at $C_2$, respectively:

[image: Step 1]

Through $C_1$ draw a line intersecting $AC_2$ at $D_1$ and $L_2$ at $E_2$, and similarly for $C_2$:

[image: Step 2]

Let $F$ be the intersection of $D_1E_1$ and $D_2E_2$:

[image: Step 3]

Points $A$, $B$ and $F$ are colinear.

In practice, it requires a bit of care to ensure that all of these points remain on the paper and within the length of the ruler.